# Midvatten on Mac High Sierra

Tags: qgis-plugins, midvatten

Is there an upgrade for Midvatten that can handle Mac OSX High Sierra. Sierra had no issues loading, but new installation of QGIS 2.18.15-4 bounces the plug-in.

Comment: Could you add the error message you get?